# Visual Studio 2019 - Debug C++ program locally (instead of remotely)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2019

I am currently using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to compile and debug a C++ program (and C programs aswell). However, it seems i can only debug using the remote debugger, and no options to debug locally appear.
It is also the only option i can select from the menu.

[image]

[image]

This is what appears when selecting that only option. It prompts me to insert some data to compile onto a linux machine:

[image]

I have tried modifying things in the options, in the project preferences, but no success.

During the installation, i have selected all the C++ packages needed for my work. Is there maybe some other thing i have to download and install in order to debug locally?

This doesn't happen in previous versions of Visual Studio (i have used 2015 in the past).

What am i missing? What am i doing wrong? Hopefully someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like your project is some type of linux project instead of a windows project.

Comment: is this c++ empty project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to debug an application under Windows, you need to select the correct type of project.

Usually:

- Windows Console Application  - A project for creating a Windows console application.
- Windows Desktop Application  - A project for creating a Windows desktop (Win32) application.

But there are many other types: [C++ project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/visual-cpp-project-types?view=vs-2019)

Because you only have options to debug using GDB, most probably the selected project is not a "Windows" project.

To change this You need to recreate the project from the begining.

Answer (score 0):

repair VS installation, also start VS as administrator and go to the JIT options page. Check all checkboxes and click OK.

tools->option->debugging->just-in-time, select native and script.